# Node - NPM Keep throwing unknown error

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I am trying to install `package.json`, But I keep getting a error as follows: how can i over come with this?

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.8",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

the error:

```
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, open 'C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sourc
e-map\0.1.34\package\package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Tutorials\Angular\Projects - Angular\IBM
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\source-map\0.1.34\pack
age\package.json
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the `npm install` was terminated by some reason and cause uncompleted package, so try the following way:

1. Remove directory `C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\source-map`
2. run `npm install` again

Comment: What's your OS? And could you copy you setps?

Comment: I use Windows7 platform

Comment: 1, Is there a file named `express.cmd` in `C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm`?

Comment: How about this: 
`npm install source-map@0.1.34 -g`

Comment: What is this? when I need to use this?

Comment: Adding `C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your OS path and try again.

Comment: I edited the path variable, and added `C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm` - But still no luck!

Comment: I think the `path` won't work before you restart OS.
Or check this: https://www.google.com.hk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=windows+path+without+restart&safe=strict

Comment: I just restart my system, not working this command (`express myApp`), and in case if i test like this `express --version` - it result me as `3.0` so globally express available but not able to install a start up app!

Comment: Try to re-install the `express` module:

`npm uninstall express`

`npm install express`

Comment: You want me to remove from global space? (`npm uninstall -g express` and `npm install -g express`)?